# Aumentar o número de colunas no histogrma

Tags: r

Olá, estou com dificuldade em aumentar o número de colunas em um histograma. Tentei mudar o número de bins de 10 para 5 mas não funcionou.

```
histograma: 

id  MCP  
#MB02   12,59
#MB03   0,001
#MB04   1,311
#MB05   0,692
#MB06   16,153
#MB07   6,861
#MB08   37,665
#MB09   5,684
#MB10   12,99
#MB11   16,912
#MB12   37,665
#MB13   5,839
#MB14   8,889
#MB15   9,33
#MB16   2,011

histo<-read.csv("histograma.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=",")
hist(histo$MCP, xlab= "MCP área (ha)", ylab = "Frequência", bin=5)
```

Comment: Duas notas: 1) em `read.csv` não é necessário `header = TRUE`, já é esse o valor; 2) para ter `sep=";", dec=","` e `header = TRUE` automaticamente existe o `read.csv2`.

Answer (score 5):

O número de colunas dos histogramas da função R base `hist` é dado pelo argumento `breaks` mas é preciso ter atenção, uma vez que com os dados da pergunta as duas instruções abaixo dão o mesmo número de colunas.

```
hist(histo$MCP)
hist(histo$MCP, breaks = 5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver, só há 4 colunas, tanto com como sem `breaks = 5`. Isto acontece porque segundo a documentação da função se `breaks` for um número, esse valor é *meramente indicativo* do número de colunas do histograma. De `help("hist")`, original.

> breaks       one of:
>
> - a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
> - a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
> - a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
> - a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells (see ‘Details’),
> - a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as the
> breakpoints will be set to
> [pretty](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/pretty.html)
> values, the number is limited to 1e6 (with a warning if it was
> larger). If breaks is a function, the x vector is supplied to it as
> the only argument (and the number of breaks is only limited by the
> amount of available memory).

Tradução Google editada por mim.

> um de:
>
> - um vetor que fornece os pontos de quebra entre as células do histograma,
> - uma função para calcular o vetor de pontos de quebra,
> - um único número que fornece o número de células para o histograma,
> - uma sequência de caracteres que nomeia um algoritmo para calcular o número de células (ver ‘Detalhes’),
> - uma função para calcular o número de células.
>
> Nos últimos três casos, o número é apenas uma sugestão; como os pontos
> de quebra serão definidos para valores bonitos
> ([pretty](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/pretty.html)),
> o número é limitado a 1e6 (com um aviso se for maior). Se breaks for
> uma função, o vetor x é fornecido a ela como o único argumento (e o
> número de quebras é limitado apenas pela quantidade de memória
> disponível).

A melhor forma de forçar a função a ter um número de colunas escolhido pelo usuário é calcular o vetor `breaks` previamente.

```
num_breaks <- 5
brks <- seq(floor(min(histo$MCP)), ceiling(max(histo$MCP)), length.out = num_breaks + 1)
```

Note que os seguintes são diferentes e é o primeiro que `hist` utiliza a não ser que `brks` seja explicitamente dado.

```
pretty(brks)
#[1]  0 10 20 30 40
brks
#[1]  0.0  7.6 15.2 22.8 30.4 38.0
```

Agora o gráfico pretendido.

```
hist(histo$MCP, breaks = brks, xlab= "MCP área (ha)", ylab = "Frequência")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados em formato `dput`**

```
histo <-
structure(list(id = c("MB02", "MB03", "MB04", "MB05", "MB06", 
"MB07", "MB08", "MB09", "MB10", "MB11", "MB12", "MB13", "MB14", 
"MB15", "MB16"), MCP = c(12.59, 0.001, 1.311, 0.692, 16.153, 
6.861, 37.665, 5.684, 12.99, 16.912, 37.665, 5.839, 8.889, 9.33, 
2.011)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `breaks`:

```
hist(histo$MCP, xlab= "MCP área (ha)", ylab = "Frequência", breaks = 5)
```

Creio que bins é utilizado no `ggplot`.

Comment: Entendi, não mudou muita coisa, realmente. Neste caso precisaria mudar a estrutura do eixo X, de forma a ficar 0-5, 5-10, 10-15 etc.?

Comment: Neste caso se você colocar o breaks = 6 ele irá de 5 em 5, só que no eixo x ele irá mostrar de 10 em 10. As barras irão de 0 - 5, 5 - 10, 10 - 15.... etc..

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada!

Comment: Por nada! Abraços!